# Custom istream operator always returning false

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ifstream, istream

I have this issue where my custom overloaded >> operator always evaluates as 'false' when I check for success. I think it may have to do with the fact that my istream is infact a redirected ifstream (meaning I passed an ifsteam to the isteam), though I'm unsure how to solve it.

Here's the code snippet, simplified as much as it can be:

```cpp
#include <istream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

class SomeClass {
public:
    SomeClass() = default;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, SomeClass& random);

private:
    std::string my_str;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, SomeClass& random) {

    while(std::getline(is, random.my_str));

    if (random.my_str != "Hello World") {
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
        return is;
    }

    is.setstate(std::ios::goodbit); //I didn't have this here before, put it in as a test
    return is;

}

bool io_parser(std::istream& input_stream) {

    SomeClass random;

    if (!(input_stream >> random))
        return false;

    return true;

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    std::cout << argc << std::endl;
    std::istream* input_stream;

    std::ifstream input_file(argv[1]);

    if (!input_file.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "File failed to open." << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    input_stream = &input_file;
    std::cout << io_parser(*input_stream) << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Sample input:

```
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
```

No matter what, it won't work as long as the std::getline() is in a while(). If it's alone, it works.

Comment: Does `input.txt` exist?

Comment: Yes. I verified the code up to that point. If I don't put the input_stream >> sudoku into a conditional, it processes correctly; meaning that the output is correct and the data loads fully.

Comment: It would be very helpful to provide a [mcve]. Remember this isn't sudoku-specific; the majority of your code can be replaced or removed to reproduce the issue, but it should still reproduce the issue. As it stands, each one of us has to create the sudoku class and fill in `/* Magic */` to even test it, and who knows what will differ from our test to your actual behaviour. You can even use http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ to set up the file contents in a way that lets us run in an exact environment that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Done, I think. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: To make this answerable, you should provide sample input as well. Concerning _No matter what, it won't work as long as the std::getline() is in a while(). If it's alone, it works._ let me think that the last line of your input is not `Hello World`. I made an even shorter [**mcve on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69d3989a18e89c76) to reproduce (what I think is) your issue. (Please, note: before I added the very last new-line (in line 9), the output was `last line: '}'`.) Btw. are you sure that the `while` shouldn't be an `if`?

Comment: It should be a while, yes. I take a file with multiple inputs and I keep processing them until eof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues.

```
while(std::getline(is, random.my_str));
```

will always keep reading and discarding lines until it encounters an error. This may be what you intended but seems odd? After this loop the stream will be in a failed state (normally with `eof` set).

```
is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
```

correctly sets the `fail` bit. However

```
is.setstate(std::ios::goodbit);
```

is not the way to return the stream to a `good` state. `setstate` adds the flag you specify to the current stream state, as `goodbit` is actually `0`, `setstate(std::ios::goodbit)` has no effect on the stream state. To set the stream state you need to call `clear`:

```
is.clear(std::ios::goodbit);
```

or for setting `std::ios::goodbit` you can just call with no arguments:

```
is.clear();
```

Comment: Wow, didn't realize that was a thing. Thank you so much